# How to further accelerate arithmetic with Fermat Pseudoprime and Fibonacci number

Tags: programming, parallelization, performance-tuning, number-theory, big-numbers

I've been working on this all night, and I have made this go pretty fast, compared to my first iteration of the program, but now I'm out of ideas.

> I'm trying to write a program to test (by good old fashioned brute force) if there is a composite positive integer $n \equiv 3 \pmod {10}$ or $n \equiv 7 \pmod {10}$ where $n$ is a Fermat Pseudoprime, and $n$ divides the $n+1^{\rm th}$ Fibonacci number.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$HistoryLength = 5; startingIter = 0; iters = startingIter; 
listLength = 10000; maxIters = 20;

nextBlock[start_, listlength_] := Block[
    {a, i},
    a = DeleteCases[
      Table[(3 + 10 i), {i, start, start + listlength - 1}], _?PrimeQ];
    a = Join[a, 
      DeleteCases[
      Table[(7 + 10 i), {i, start, start + listlength - 1}], _?PrimeQ]];

    a = DeleteCases[a, Except[_?(Divisible[Fibonacci[# + 1], #] &)]];
    a = DeleteCases[a, Except[_?(Divisible[2^(# - 1) - 1, #] &)]];


    Print["Found ", Length[a], " candidates (3 + 10n) or (7 + 10n) between
         ", TraditionalForm[start], " and ", (start + listLength - 1), "."];
    a
];

Monitor[
    Do[
        Print[
            "Iteration: ", ToString[iters + 1], ". Currently testing around: ", ToString[7 + 10*(1 + iters*listLength)], " and a Fibbonaci number with : ", Length[IntegerDigits[Fibonacci[7 + 10*(1 + iters*listLength)]]], " digits: ", nextBlock[1 + iters*listLength, listLength]
        ],
    {iters, startingIter, maxIters}], 
    ProgressIndicator[iters, {startingIter, maxIters}]
 ]
```

The strategy here is that each time **nextBlock[]** is called, it first creates a list of all composite integers in the desired range which are congruent to $3$ or $7 \mod 10$. Next, it removes any which do not divide the appropriate Fibonacci number, and then removes any that are not Fermat Pseudo-prime. It's fast enough on my system to do 20 iterations in a reasonable amount of time.

Basically I have no clue what to do next to speed this up. I've looked into `Compile[]` but the Fibonacci numbers in question have hundreds of thousands of digits, so I can't do that. If anyone is good with parallelization, I could use some guidance since the documentation is difficult to follow. I have an i7 CPU and access to another PC with *Mathematica* and 4 cores, so if I could figure that out I would probably speed things up a bunch.

I haven't done anything with GPU acceleration in many years, is it possible to port GMP onto CUDA or OpenCL?

Comment: Since it's a brute force search anyway, you might as well use `FindInstance`. Could you verify that this is equivalent: 
`FindInstance[
 (Mod[n, 10] == 3 || Mod[n, 10] == 7) &&
  Mod[Fibonacci[n + 1], n] == 0 &&
  Mod[2^(n - 1) - 1, n] == 0 &&
  Not[Element[n, Primes]] && n > 0, n, Integers, 1]`

  It will probably sit there for billions of years or forever. Are you sure there is a single number that satisfies these constraints? If you want a faster solution you'll have to use a more intelligent algorithm than brute force.

Comment: It's an open problem. Such a number would be a counterexample to a certain probabilistic Primality test. Really, this is more an interesting exercise for me to get better with Mathematica.

Comment: Well, I just ran FindInstance for a good length of time and it failed to either prove no such number existed or find any number... so my approach doesn't work :(

Comment: It is known that any such number is greater than $2^{64}$

Comment: ahh, well that explains it : `Fibonacci[2^64 + 1]` gives `Overflow[ ]` I'm thinking you might be able to leverage the Fibonacci square test somehow to avoid calculating the Fib altogether, if either (5 (k+1)^2 + 4) or (5 (k+1)^2 - 4) is square, k+1 is a Fibonacci number... tricky

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Never use pattern matching unless you absolutely have to. Using `Cases` instead of `Select` can make a huge difference.
2. Vectorize operations. Use `Range` instead of `Table` if you can.
3. Test several things at once. `And[test1, test2, test3]` will abort when it can for maximum efficiency ("short circuit evaluation").

Taking this into consideration your code looks like this:

```
nextBlock2[start_, listlength_] := Module[{a},
  a = 10 Range[start, start + listlength - 1];
  a = Join[3 + a, 7 + a];
  Select[a, And[
     Not@*PrimeQ,
     Divisible[Fibonacci[# + 1], #] &,
     Divisible[2^(# - 1) - 1, #] &
     ]]
  ]
```

And it should be much faster.

Comment: This is great, thanks for your help! The only other change I made was to switch the order of Fermat-Pseudoprime testing and fibonacci testing since the fibonacci numbers are so big, so I'm eliminating more with the first test.

Comment: One more thing: I'd use `PowerMod[]` instead of using `Divisible[]` on a big pseudoprime for testing Fermat's little theorem.